# I would like to know how to insert my name into a message. eg:“xxx is taking the course CSCP1014"

Tags: java

```
//This program prints welcome to April Semester 2014!
public class April {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to April Semester 2014!");


   }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? What did you tried?

Comment: Hint: see `String [] args` or use `Scanner.readLine()`

Comment: Your name will be hardcoded or will you type it for the program?

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-accept-text-input-in-a-console-application.html Maybe this helps

Comment: You can start learning **java** to do that !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your intention is, but maybe this is what you were aiming for:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        name = kb.next();
        System.out.println(name + " is now taking the course CSP1014");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take in an input and then process that input into your output.

One way to take in the input would be the Scanner.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = in.nextLine();
```